# Undefined variable error when no MySQL query produces no results

Tags: php, mysql

I am running the following query:

```
$cv_specs = select("SELECT * FROM file_details WHERE client_details_id='$cv_specs_id'");
```

Through the function *select* :

```
function select($query) {
        $mysqli = connect();

        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        while ( $obj = $result->fetch_object() ) {
            $return[] = $obj;
        }

        return $return;
    }
```

This all works fine provided there are results returned. However, if there are no results found then the page it's included from errors as follows:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: return
```

I get that $return is not defined in the function if there are no results, but can't get it to work trying to update the function to set a different variable if there are no results.

Comment: Why not just declare `$return = array();` before the while loop?

Comment: The lack of dynamic language...

Comment: **DO NOT** put variables in your queries. Use the [SQL placeholder system](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and the [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method to create your query. What you're doing here is extremely dangerous.

Comment: Thats why it's a good practice to explicit initialize variables even when it's a language with dynamic types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variable: `$return = array();` Problem solved.

But I really hope you're not creating a new database connection every single time you want to select data, and never closing any of those connections...

Comment: @Kolink...as someone who's a total beginner it's worrying that you're not the first person to have mentioned this, any pointers to code that shows a better way of nesting queries? Or is it just that I should be killing the connection after each?

Comment: You should establish a connection at the start of your script, and then reuse it. Now, you could do something like `function connect() {static $res = null; if( !$res) { $res = /* whatever you use to create the connection here */ } return $res;}` as that will work nicely.

Comment: Thanks @Kolink - this was a function being used in a tutorial book so I never questioned its integrity!

Answer (score 3):

```
    $return = array();
    while ( $obj = $result->fetch_object() ) {
        $return[] = $obj;
    }

    return $return;
```

Define it first.